# Using an older version of JRE for certain programs

Tags: java

I have learned that on my computer, Minecraft will only run with Java 6 installed.  As soon as I install java 7 (JDK or otherwise), the application encounters multiple problems (doesn't crash, just can't connect to any file servers.)  My question is: Is there a way to allow Minecraft to use Java 6 while all other programs use 7?

Comment: Is your computer 64-bit? Minecraft only works for me if I use the 64-bit Java 7 JRE.

Comment: Have you taken this issue up with Mojang directly? They would be able to help.

Comment: I'll try, but their customer service is pretty bad.

Comment: @JeffDemanche You should migrate this question to SuperUser. They definitely have better advive for this type of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed 2 versions: JRE 6 and JRE 7. They were stored in Program Files\Java folder.

To run your program in JRE 6:
- The first way, you must re-config Environment Variables and then run command / terminal to interpre your program.
 java yourfolder\yoursubfolder\yourMain

yourMain is a file "yourMain.class"

- The second way, you must change your current directory to JRE 6 Folder in Program Files\Java, you can do that in command / terminal (ex: DOS...). And then, you use java command normally.